# how to add a new value to a dropdown list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my item table, I have a itemname column which is currently a dropdown list taking values from DB.

```
<%= select 'item','itemname',
   Item.find(:all).collect{|c| [c.itemname]},{:include_blank => 'Select Name'} %>
```

How can I add a new value to this dropdown list through the application. Is there a provision to directly add value to the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

```
<%= select 'item','itemname',
   Item.all.map{|c| [c.itemname]}.concat(["Foo Item", "Bar Item"]),
   {:include_blank => 'Select Name'} %>
```